# Facing issue with JPA Hikari Transaction Mangaement

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I am using JPA , HikariPool to add entries in DB .
I am facing issue while saving the transaction .
Here is my main class

```
package com.vish.jpa_demo;

import com.vish.jpa_demo.config.AppConfig;
import com.vish.jpa_demo.model.Laptop;
import com.vish.jpa_demo.model.Student;
import com.vish.jpa_demo.service.DBService;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
public class JpaDemoApplication
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        log.info("Starting Main");
        SpringApplication.run(JpaDemoApplication.class, args);

        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(JpaDemoApplication.class);

        Student s = new Student("Vish");
        Laptop laptop = new Laptop("HP");

        s.setLaptop(laptop);

        DBService dbService =applicationContext.getBean(DBService.class);

        try
        {
            dbService.addLaptop(laptop);
            dbService.addStudent(s);
            laptop.setBrand("Apple");
            dbService.addLaptop(laptop);
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        log.info("Exiting Main");

    }

}
```

Here is my AppConfig

```
package com.vish.jpa_demo.config;


import com.vish.jpa_demo.service.DBService;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringBootConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@EnableTransactionManagement
@Configuration
public class AppConfig
{
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter getJpaVendorAdapter()
    {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
        return jpaVendorAdapter;
    }


    @Bean
    public DataSource getHikariDataSource()
    {
        final HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test");
        dataSource.setUsername("XXXXX");
        dataSource.setPassword("XXXX");
        dataSource.setAutoCommit(false);
        //dataSource.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(1000);
        //dataSource.setCacheState(false);s
        dataSource.setConnectionTimeout(31000);
        dataSource.setIdleTimeout(30000);
        dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(2);
        dataSource.setMinimumIdle(0);
        dataSource.setConnectionTimeout(60000);


        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityMangerFactory()
    {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(getHikariDataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(getJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(DBProperties());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("com.vish.jpa_demo");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.vish.jpa_demo.model");
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }


    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager()
    {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(getEntityMangerFactory().getNativeEntityManagerFactory());
        transactionManager.setDataSource(getHikariDataSource());
        return transactionManager;
    }
    private final Properties DBProperties()
    {
        final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();

        hibernateProperties.put("javax.persistence.transactionType", "RESOURCE_LOCAL");

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

       //hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class","org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext");
       hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class","org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext");

        return hibernateProperties;
    }

}
```

Here is my DaoImpl Class .
Here I am trying to add one object .
Transaction is already started in Service class and I am using the same in Dao

```
package com.vish.jpa_demo.dao;

import com.vish.jpa_demo.model.Laptop;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.hibernate.ScrollMode;
import org.hibernate.ScrollableResults;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Slf4j
@Repository
@Data
public class LaptopDaoImpl implements ILaptopDao
{
    private Session session = null;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    private EntityManager entityManager ;




    private  void  setEntityMangerFactoryCurrentSession()
    {
        if ( this.session == null  )
        {
            //this.session =  this.entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager().unwrap(Session.class).getSessionFactory().openSession();
            this.session =  this.entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager().unwrap(Session.class).getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void addLaptop(Laptop laptop)
    {
        log.info("Adding Laptop " + laptop.getBrand());
        setEntityMangerFactoryCurrentSession();
        this.session.save(laptop);

    }

    @Override
    public Laptop getLaptopDetailsByName(String name)
    {
        Laptop invalidlaptop = null ;

        try
        {

            setEntityMangerFactoryCurrentSession();
            String myQry = "from Laptop where brand = :bname";
            Query query = session.createQuery(myQry,Laptop.class);
            query.setParameter("bname",name);

            query.setFetchSize(1);
            ScrollableResults scrollableResults = query.setReadOnly(true).scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
            while(true)
            {
                for (;scrollableResults.next();  )
                {
                    List<Object> objectList = Arrays.asList(scrollableResults.get());
                    Optional<Laptop> laptop  = objectList
                            .stream()
                            .map(e -> (Laptop) e )
                            .filter(e2  -> e2.getBrand().equalsIgnoreCase(name))
                            .findFirst();

                    return laptop.orElse(invalidlaptop);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return invalidlaptop;
    }
}
```

Here is my Service Class

```
package com.vish.jpa_demo.service;

import com.vish.jpa_demo.dao.ILaptopDao;
import com.vish.jpa_demo.dao.IStudentDao;
import com.vish.jpa_demo.model.Laptop;
import com.vish.jpa_demo.model.Student;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.hibernate.ScrollMode;
import org.hibernate.ScrollableResults;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;


@Data
@Slf4j
@Component
public class DBService
{
    private Session session = null;

    @Autowired(required = false )
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    private IStudentDao studentDao;

    @Autowired
    private ILaptopDao laptopDao;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = {Exception.class})
    public void addStudent(Student student) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            studentDao.addStudent(student);
        }
       

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = {Exception.class})
    public void addLaptop(Laptop laptop) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            laptopDao.addLaptop(laptop);
        }


        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Actual Error

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\java.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:57158,suspend=y,server=n -javaagent:C:\Users\VISHBA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\captureAgent251jars\debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\rt.jar;F:\Java\VD_program\java_prog\SpringBoot_JPA_Hikari\jpa_demo\target\classes;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.4.1\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.4.1.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.4.1\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.4.1.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.2\spring-aop-5.3.2.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.6\aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.4.1\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.4.1.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.3.2\spring-jdbc-5.3.2.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.4.25.Final\hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.1.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.10.18\byte-buddy-1.10.18.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.1.3.Final\jandex-2.1.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\dom4j\dom4j\2.1.3\dom4j-2.1.3.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.2.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.3\jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.3\txw2-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.11\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.11.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\com\sun\activation\jakarta.activation\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.4.2\spring-data-jpa-2.4.2.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.4.2\spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.3.2\spring-orm-5.3.2.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.2\spring-context-5.3.2.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.2\spring-expression-5.3.2.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.3.2\spring-tx-5.3.2.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.2\spring-beans-5.3.2.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.3.2\spring-aspects-5.3.2.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.16\lombok-1.18.16.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.4.1\spring-boot-starter-2.4.1.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.4.1\spring-boot-2.4.1.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.4.1\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.1.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.4.1\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.4.1.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.13.3\log4j-to-slf4j-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.13.3\log4j-api-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.30\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.30.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.27\snakeyaml-1.27.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.3\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.2\spring-core-5.3.2.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.2\spring-jcl-5.3.2.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\2.2.5\HikariCP-2.2.5.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.30\slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.18.1-GA\javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar;C:\Users\VIsh bade\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.13\mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.1\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.vish.jpa_demo.JpaDemoApplication
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57158', transport: 'socket'
08:48:32.958 [main] INFO com.vish.jpa_demo.JpaDemoApplication - Starting Main

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.1)

2020-12-17 08:48:33.751  INFO 5184 --- [           main] com.vish.jpa_demo.JpaDemoApplication     : Starting JpaDemoApplication using Java 1.8.0_231 on LAPTOP-SDUPSP61 with PID 5184 (F:\Java\VD_program\java_prog\SpringBoot_JPA_Hikari\jpa_demo\target\classes started by VIsh bade in F:\Java\VD_program\java_prog\SpringBoot_JPA_Hikari\jpa_demo)
2020-12-17 08:48:33.753  INFO 5184 --- [           main] com.vish.jpa_demo.JpaDemoApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-12-17 08:48:33.910  INFO 5184 --- [           main] com.vish.jpa_demo.JpaDemoApplication     : Started JpaDemoApplication in 0.736 seconds (JVM running for 1.33)
2020-12-17 08:48:34.718  INFO 5184 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: com.vish.jpa_demo]
2020-12-17 08:48:34.826  INFO 5184 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.25.Final
2020-12-17 08:48:35.019  INFO 5184 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2020-12-17 08:48:35.370  INFO 5184 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariCP pool HikariPool-0 is starting.
2020-12-17 08:48:36.133  INFO 5184 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2020-12-17 08:48:36.610  INFO 5184 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator     : HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: com.vish.jpa_demo.model.Laptop (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
2020-12-17 08:48:36.864  INFO 5184 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator     : HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: com.vish.jpa_demo.model.Student (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
2020-12-17 08:48:36.992  INFO 5184 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'com.vish.jpa_demo'
2020-12-17 08:48:50.258  INFO 5184 --- [           main] com.vish.jpa_demo.dao.LaptopDaoImpl      : Adding Laptop HP
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Calling method 'save' is not valid without an active transaction (Current status: NOT_ACTIVE)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:347)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.vish.jpa_demo.dao.LaptopDaoImpl.addLaptop(LaptopDaoImpl.java:51)
    at com.vish.jpa_demo.service.DBService.addLaptop(DBService.java:61)
    at com.vish.jpa_demo.service.DBService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ffafa2f0.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at com.vish.jpa_demo.service.DBService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5cfb11dd.addLaptop(<generated>)
    at com.vish.jpa_demo.JpaDemoApplication.main(JpaDemoApplication.java:37)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57158', transport: 'socket'
2020-12-17 08:51:03.970  INFO 5184 --- [           main] com.vish.jpa_demo.dao.StudentDaoImpl     : Adding Student Vish
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Calling method 'save' is not valid without an active transaction (Current status: NOT_ACTIVE)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:347)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.vish.jpa_demo.dao.StudentDaoImpl.addStudent(StudentDaoImpl.java:44)
    at com.vish.jpa_demo.service.DBService.addStudent(DBService.java:46)
    at com.vish.jpa_demo.service.DBService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ffafa2f0.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at com.vish.jpa_demo.service.DBService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5cfb11dd.addStudent(<generated>)
    at com.vish.jpa_demo.JpaDemoApplication.main(JpaDemoApplication.java:38)
2020-12-17 08:51:03.975  INFO 5184 --- [           main] com.vish.jpa_demo.dao.LaptopDaoImpl      : Adding Laptop Apple
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Calling method 'save' is not valid without an active transaction (Current status: NOT_ACTIVE)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:347)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.vish.jpa_demo.dao.LaptopDaoImpl.addLaptop(LaptopDaoImpl.java:51)
    at com.vish.jpa_demo.service.DBService.addLaptop(DBService.java:61)
    at com.vish.jpa_demo.service.DBService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ffafa2f0.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at com.vish.jpa_demo.service.DBService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5cfb11dd.addLaptop(<generated>)
    at com.vish.jpa_demo.JpaDemoApplication.main(JpaDemoApplication.java:40)
2020-12-17 08:51:03.980  INFO 5184 --- [           main] com.vish.jpa_demo.JpaDemoApplication     : Exiting Main

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Entire code is available at https://github.com/vishy-wisy/Java/tree/main/jpa_demo

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Add the `@Tramsactional` annottation to your `addLaptop(..)` method. As an aside you cpould probably remove 90% of your code and still get the same functionality. See, for example: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: @Alan Hay :Thanks for your reply . If I add "@Transaction" inside DaoImpl class then it will be separate transaction from Service , right ? I want everything should be controlled from Service and not DaoImpl . Is there any problem in this approach ? I will go through the standard documentation you shared . Thanks again .

Comment: Yes, normally define transactions at the service layer but you did not post that. So, ye if you already have a transaction started then  it would work but clearly you don't. And i am not sure what you are doing with Session/EntityManagerfactory/EntityManager in your DAO. Read the guide and start again. As I say you can remove 90% of the code you have posted and get the same (and more) functionality out of the box.

Comment: @AlanHay , please check now . I copy pasted Service class code . "@Transaction" is already there . Document is showing one way to achieve it which may be the best , I am not denying that .My question is what is wrong in the way I am doing . I want to learn EntityManager and EnityMangerFactroy so I was doing some experimenting .